# Minimising the surface area of a Cuboid with a different length, width, and height.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I've been trying to minimise the surface of a Cuboid, with a different length, width, and height, but I haven't been able to do so, considering that there is more than 2 variables.

The constraint being the volume of the cuboid.

Considering the following equations:

S.A of cuboid = 2(wl+hl+hw)
V = whl

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "Minimise" subject to what constraints?? If there are no constraints then the $0 \times 0 \times 0$ cuboid would have the smallest surface area

Comment: @glowstonetrees the constraint would be the volume of the Cuboid.

Comment: You can set the variables to be the length $l$ and width $w$, and the height is known because volume is constant. Therefore, you only have two variables. Then look at the area of the cuboid, $A=A(l,w)$. You need to find the values of length and width so that that function gets the minimum value.

Comment: @MattiP. With two variables still remaining unknown, it wouldn't be possible to find the first derivative.

Comment: @hhalaweh Say me please.Is the volum a constant?

Comment: @hhalaweh Actually we're not only looking for the derivative, but the gradient of the function. We want the gradient of $A$ to be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it means that the volum $V$ is given we can make the following.

By AM-GM
$$2(wl+hl+hw)\geq2\cdot3\sqrt[3]{wl\cdot hl\cdot hw}=6\sqrt[3]{w^2l^2h^2}=6\sqrt[3]{V^2}.$$

The equality occurs for $w=l=h,$ which is impossible by the given.

Id est, the minimal value does not exist, but the infimum is $6\sqrt[3]{V^2}.$

Comment: can I use the infimum to find the minimum surface area?

Comment: @hhalaweh No, because the minimum does not occur. If $w$, $l$ and $h$ can be equal then the infimum is equal to the minimum.